# Custom font are not showing in new storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created my new storyboard file and added some fonts in info.plist. These fonts are showing in main.storyboard but In my created storyboard, these are not reflected. I am using Xcode 9.1.

Comment: Set the text to be attributed on the label. Then select the font you need. Then swap back to plain text. This usually works but you might need to combine it with restarting Xcode.

Comment: It's also not showing inside attributed fonts.

Comment: Then ensure your fonts are installed. Double click on them and you will get the installer... After you installed them try restarting everything (your mac as well) just in case..

Comment: These fonts are showing inside main storyboard. This project was developed on another machine. Now I'm working on another machine. it might be issue?

Comment: Yes, your fonts may not be installed on this new machine. Use application "Font Book" to check if they are there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The project was developed on another machine. So these fonts were not installed on my machine. I just double click on all fonts and clean the project and Quit the Xcode and open again. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

If everything you done right then just check Target Membership if its check box check marked or not, if not then Checked it mark.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I have checked, all fonts are added into target. These fonts also showing on  main storyboard.

Comment: This project was developed on another machine. Now I'm working on another machine. it might be issue?